# chaging directory saved in sd card

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I've created this code to save a pdf file in sd card, but I want to change the directory that has the saved files, from /sdcard/, to /sdcard/MYDIR/

```
 try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/yes.pdf");
```

Comment: have to creat the dir and see if it's already exsits

Comment: how can I create the dirctory? I don't know the codes ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a directory in Java, use `mkdir()` or `mkdirs()` on `File`.

To **correctly** create a directory or file on external storage on Android, do **not** hard-code `/sdcard`, largely because it is the wrong value on most Android devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to access the root of external storage.

```
File dir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MYDIR");

dir.mkdir();

OutputStream output=new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, "yes.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The class you need is [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). There you have methods like `mkdirs()` that creates the necessary directories.

You should make sure that you don't use hard coded paths in your application. On some devices your `"/sdcard/"` will fail. Check the class [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) and use the `getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path of the sd card.